# Use more than one neo4j graph database at same time

Tags: database, neo4j

Each time I want to use a different database I open neo4j.conf file and change this line:

```
dbms.active_database
```

Now how can I use different neo4j graph databases at same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have multiple databases loaded at the same time, however, you can have 2 instances of neo4j running at the time, just make sure to change the the default ports on one of them, otherwise you will have conflicts.